# Hibernate Cache Level 2 - what to check before switching on?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

We are running a small SaaS service and would like to start using one of the Hibernate level-2 caches that are out there (EHCache or JBOSS cache).

Assuming that the problems caused by cache can be evasive and are hard-to-catch and reproduce, I wonder, what is it that we need to check in our code before switching on the Hibernate cache? What I mean, is there some hibernate functions or object manipulations that are not permitted?

Also, is there a way to turn on the cache in a step-by-step fashion? I.e. not all of the functions but just some of them?

Comment: [this](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-hibernate-second-level-cache-works.html) might help you to some extent

Comment: thanks, I understand the reasoning and principles of 2 level cache, I'm more wondering what precautions should we take to introduce it. I'm specifically afraid of cases when users complain of evasive, non-reproducible problems that cache may introduce.

Comment: Some basics: Make sure you actually need it (i.e. measure, don't guess) first; as you plug it into Hibernate, measure what you'd actually cache (e.g. entities, relationships, queries?!); see what this then would mean to your app (e.g. during bulk update ops); then see what topology you'd actually need (e.g. all on heap? distributed cache?); finally, test! And I mean perf test as well. You probably really want to know how Hibernate uses a cache (given the strategy), how the cache works and finally how the topology might impact runtime perf. Depending on the answers, different caveats apply.

Comment: "step-by-step fashion? I.e. not all of the functions but just some of them" ?! What functions are you referring to here?

Comment: Alex, really appreciate your comment. Our idea is to implement caching now, despite there is no immediate need (some performance improvement would not hurt, but not critical). The reason is to let users use and tester test already today with caches enabled, in order to avoid introduction of this later when system will develop a lot, and therefore doing full regression testing. The system is still small so now is less pain. Do you think that makes sense?